# Documenter.jl: @ref a specific method of a function

Tags: julia

Let's say I have two methods

```
"""
    f(x::Integer)

Integer version of `f`.
"""
f(x::Integer) = println("I'm an integer!")

"""
    f(x::Float64)

Float64 version of `f`.
"""
f(x::Float64) = println("I'm floating!")
```

and produce doc entries for those methods in my documentation using Documenter.jl's `@autodocs` or `@docs`.

**How can I refer (with `@ref`) to one of the methods?**

I'm searching for something like `[integer version](@ref f(::Integer))` (which unfortunately does not work) rather than just `[function f](@ref f)` or `[f](@ref)`.

Note that for generating the doc entries `@docs` has a similar feature. From the [guide page](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/guide/#Filtering-Included-Docstrings-1):

> [...] include the type in the signature with
>
> ````
> ```@docs
> length(::T)
> ```
> ````

Thanks in advance.

x-ref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/documenter-jl-ref-a-specific-method-of-a-function/8792

x-ref: https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl/issues/569#issuecomment-362760811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @mortenpi on Discourse and github:

> You would normally refer to a function with `` [`f`](@ref) ``, with the name
>   of the function being referred to between backticks in text part of
>   the link. You can then also refer to specific signatures, e.g. with
>   `` [`f(::Integer)`](@ref) ``.
>
> The @ref section in the docs should be updated to mention this
>   possibility.